# ページングで使用するデータを取得するため、LIMIT と OFFSET を使用したいのですが、全体件数を割り出すためには事前にSQLを実行するしかない？

Tags: php, mysql

**ページングで使用するデータを取得するため、LIMIT と OFFSET を使用したいのですが、

LIMIT と OFFSET を決めるためには、最初に全体件数を取得する必要があると思います**

---

**Q.1回のSQLで処理することは出来ない？**
・「たくさん結合しているSQL」なので出来れば1回で済ませたい場合でも、全体件数を取得するためには最初にSQL実行するしか手はないのでしょうか？

**処理の流れ**
・最初に件数を取得するためだけにSQL文を実行して全体件数を取得し、そこから割り出した、LIMIT と OFFSET を使用し、実際にデータを取得するしかない？
・結局、同じSQLを2回実行せざるを得ない？

---

**追記**
・Google検索のようなイメージです

> FITSTへ 前へ 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 次へ LASTへ

・データはMySQLへ格納している前提
・例えば、500件データを格納している内のSELECT結果が200件だった場合、1ページ表示数に応じて分割して取得
・1ページ表示数10件と指定した場合は、全部で200ページに分割して表示

Comment: どのようなデータを、どのようなページ割で表示したいのですか？　百科事典のようなコンテンツで、１回のSQLで１項目分のデータが得られるのであれば、それを必要に応じて複数ページに表示する事は可能です。次の項目は新しいページから始めれば良いのですから。　表示する内容と、それの表示イメージを具体的に示してもらわないと、質問者が抱えている問題が理解できないです。

Comment: ＠ Fumu 7さん、追記しました

Comment: 結果件数をサーバー側で保持しておけませんか？ そうすれば＋１回で済むかと。

Comment: なるほど。やはりどう考えても＋１回は必要なのですね。もしかすると1回で済ませる方法があるかなと思ったのですが…

Comment: 1度のリクエストでということなら、サブクエリを使用してカウントはできるかと思いますが、それでも、クエリを一度多く投げているだけですからね…。lengthをDB外で持ってしまうと、更新タイミングによっては最新の最大件数が取得できず情報の鮮度が落ちる気はしますね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL の SELECT には SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS オプションというのがあります。
このオプションをつけて LIMIT つきの SELECT を実行後、FOUND_ROWS() 関数で全件数を取得することが出来ます。

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Answer (score 0):

最初から全件取得して、その結果の配列からページングに応じてデータを切り出すようにすれば、SQLの実行自体は一回で済みますね。

Answer (score 0):

1ページあたりの件数とページ番号からOFFSETを計算することができます。

```
$limit = $_GET['limit']; //1ページ内の件数
$page  = $_GET['page']; //ページ番号
$offset = $limit * ($page-1); //読み飛ばす件数
$sql = "SELECT * from t LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset}";
```

このような形でOFFSETを算出できる状況であれば、データ全件取得する必要はありません。